# Wordpress, Woocommerce Storefront Related Products

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I would like to move the Related Products on the Products page to a lower position with a full width column, so I have defined the following in the functions.php file to do just that;

```
// Move related products
   remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
   add_action('storefront_before_footer','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
```

However, by doing so the related products now presumably are outside of some important loop, because they are now being displayed on the category archive pages.

Does anyone know of (a) How to either restrict the output to product pages (without display:none; in the style sheet) -or- (b) another defined position where I can place the content outside (below) the div and presumably sidebar but retain relevance of the related products to the product page displayed?

I'd prefer not to be trying to re-engineer the html output for the and , I'm sure you'll understand that doing so would have a great deal of impact.

Another idea I guess (whilst not ideal or the right way), could be to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: This should restrict the output to product pages.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);

add_action('storefront_before_footer','woo_related_product_addition');

function woo_related_product_addition() {

    global $post;

    if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
      add_action('storefront_before_footer','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you...

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);

add_action('storefront_before_footer','woo_related_product_addition');

function woo_related_product_addition() {

    global $post;

    if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );

    if ($product->is_type( 'single' || 'grouped' || 'external' || 'variable' )) {
      add_action('storefront_before_footer','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT 2: You could then remove the products from the archive pages by doing something like.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woo_related_product_removal');

function woo_related_product_removal() {

    global $post;

    if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );

    if (!$product->is_type( 'single' || 'grouped' || 'external' || 'variable' )) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: shortcode is easier to use in some cases as you can just write it directly into your product page at the desired location and specify products per page and columns, I fail to see what you find unclear?

Comment: I'm with @cale_b on this answer, sorry this is just another example of doing what I have already done.

Comment: yes i see the problem one moment I think i have a solution for you i think i just read it to fast will revise answer..

Comment: try that not tested but should stop related products showing up in the wrong place

Comment: Well it looked promising and I thought this would work, however to doesn't.  I presumed you forgot to comment out line two?  With it commented out there is no output.  Of course if I comment out there is but sadly on the archive page as well.

Comment: that means your archive page is specifically calling the related products the second line should not be commented out as that calls in the function

Comment: Edit 2, did it!! Perfect! Thanks Scott.